# How to get the innerHTML of selectable jquery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml, selectable

I have a php generated list whose list items are selectable using jquery selectable widget. The list for all intents and purposes is:

```
<ul id="#select-image">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery selectable is declared as:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#select-image").selectable({
            selected: function( event, ui ) { 
                var $variable = $('.ui-selected').innerHTML; 
                console.log($variable);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

An event takes place after a list item has been selected, in the example it outputs to the browser console. The output however is "undefined." The selector `$('.ui-selected').` is correct as it shows as an object in the browser's console. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think innerHTML() only works for document elements, not jQuery objects. Use .html() instead

Comment: `<ul id="#select-image">` would not be matched by `$("#select-image")`, you need to make it `<ul id="select-image">` for the selector to match it. I'm not sure if this is the case in your actual HTML or just a typo in the sample above.

Comment: – Kiro Coneski is has found the problem and the solution. I suggest he posts it as an answer so I can give it a green tick.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: html() worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Use `.val()` instead of `.innerHTML` for getting value of selected option

Use `.text()` for getting text of selected option

Thanks for correcting  :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function() {
        $("#select-image").selectable({
            selected: function( event, ui ) { 
                var $variable = $('.ui-selected').html(); 
                console.log($variable);
            }
        });
    });
```

or

```
$(function() {
        $("#select-image").selectable({
            selected: function( event, ui ) { 
                var $variable = $('.ui-selected').text(); 
                console.log($variable);
            }
        });
    });
```

or

```
$(function() {
        $("#select-image").selectable({
            selected: function( event, ui ) { 
                var $variable = $('.ui-selected').val(); 
                console.log($variable);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `ui` has a property called `selected` which is a reference to the selected dom element, you can call `innerHTML` on that element.

Your code `$('.ui-selected').innerHTML` tries to return the `innerHTML` property of a jQuery wrapper element for a dom element with class `ui-selected`

```
$(function () {
    $("#select-image").selectable({
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            var $variable = ui.selected.innerHTML; // or $(ui.selected).html()
            console.log($variable);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2mNF7/)